# Convert list of dictionary into list

Tags: python, list

i have a data in this format:

```
[{"user": "fgb59h", "id": 4, "text": 'hello'},

{"user": "bucho_ky", "id": 20, "text": 'why'},

{"user": "redp944", "id": 40, "text": 'this is an example'},
]
```

i want to select the 'text' and convert it to:

```
 ['hello','why','this is an example']
```

so that i can perform text analysis on the data.

How should I do this?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
DATA = [{"user": "fgb59h", "id": 4, "text": 'hello'},

{"user": "bucho_ky", "id": 20, "text": 'why'},

{"user": "redp944", "id": 40, "text": 'this is an example'},
]

result = [i['text'] for i in DATA]
print(result)
```